# Get token id from Login request in Gatling

Tags: scala, performance-testing, access-token, gatling, scala-gatling

I am using Gatling for performance testing, so I want know that how we extract token id from the login request here is code

```
val scn = scenario("Navigation")
    .exec(http("request_6")
        .post("/WEBAUTO03/aurora/login/security_check")
        .headers(headers_6)
        .formParam("j_username", "TONY")
        .formParam("j_password", "1234")
        .formParam("doLogin", "")
```

Above request provide token and I need apply the token in following request

```
val headers_9 = Map(
    "Content-type" -> "text/plain",
    "Origin" -> "https://resource.com",
    "X-XSRF-TOKEN" -> ""4c81ed9c-e509-4830-b724-62e489c918e2"")       -----here i need to replace token 


        .exec(http("request_9")
        .post("/WEBAUTO03/aurora/JSON-RPC")
        .headers(headers_9)
        .body(RawFileBody("webview/navigation/0009_request.txt")))
```

anyone have any idea

Comment: Depends on the response. My example: `check(jsonPath("$.access_token").saveAs("ACCESS_TOKEN")))`

Comment: This is the kind of things you learn from the official documentation, in particular the tutorials (https://gatling.io/docs/current/advanced_tutorial/) and the Gatling Academy (https://gatling.io/academy/).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the response from the "above request" we cannot suggest the exact steps, approximate would be something like:

```
http("request_6")
.post("/WEBAUTO03/aurora/login/security_check")
.check(css("input[name='csrf_token']", "value").saveAs("Correlation1"))

val headers_9 = Map(
"Content-type" -> "text/plain",
"Origin" -> "https://resource.com",
"X-CSRF-Token" -> "${Correlation1}")
```

More information:

- [Gatling HTTP Checks](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_check/)
- [How to Run a Simple Load Test with Gatling](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-run-a-simple-load-test-with-gatling)